# My function filling string value

Tags: c, linux, string, function

I have the following function

```
void runSysCall(char *command, char *output)
{

    FILE *cmdline = popen(command, "rb");
    size_t size = 0;


    while(getdelim(&output, &size, 0, cmdline) != -1);

    fclose(cmdline);
}
```

I am calling it from this function and what ever I am returning is null.

```
char * getVendorOfTheProcesses()
{

    char * result = 0;
    runSysCall("cat /proc/cpuinfo | grep -i 'Model'", result);

    printf("%s", result);
    return "asdsd";
}
```

If you print the result value from the function it will give what it supposed to printout.

Please any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You probably mean `getdelim(output, &size, 0, cmdline)`. Make sure to enable all compiler warnings.

Comment: @KerrekSB - Yes and no : `getdelim` needs `char**` as first param. but `output` is only `char *`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please change your

```
FILE *cmdline = popen(command, "rb");
```

to

```
FILE *cmdline = popen(command, "r");
```

and it works (I tested it -- http://ideone.com/agV18s).

From http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009696899/functions/popen.html

> The mode argument to popen() is a string that specifies I/O mode:
>
> If mode is r, when the child process is started, its file descriptor
>   STDOUT_FILENO shall be the writable end of the pipe, and the file
>   descriptor fileno(stream) in the calling process, where stream is the
>   stream pointer returned by popen(), shall be the readable end of the
>   pipe.
>
> If mode is w, when the child process is started its file descriptor
>   STDIN_FILENO shall be the readable end of the pipe, and the file
>   descriptor fileno(stream) in the calling process, where stream is the
>   stream pointer returned by popen(), shall be the writable end of the
>   pipe.
>
> If mode is any other value, the result is undefined.

It seems you using `b` mode is causing the issue (or getting undefined behavior).

Also make sure to `free` all your pointers to avoid memory leaks.

Also note that each iteration of `runSysCall` will overwrite `output`. Thus, in your `getVendorOfTheProcesses` when you print `result`, you will get `null`, since that is the last thing being read. So you have to make sure you append each line and return that to `runSysCall` instead of using `result`.

I changed your code a bit to incorporate what I mean -- http://ideone.com/QVTjiD
This is just an example, you should adapt it for your own needs and incorporate memory management.

To verify that your code is working fine (on my machine the count was 128, your may be different), you can use something like below:

```
$ cat /proc/cpuinfo | grep -i 'Model' | wc -l
128
$ ./a.out | wc -l
128
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Your first ideone is flawed : The `printf("%s", result);` is writing the `(null)`!

Comment: @Roddy It is not flawed, it is what @Alibaba has. I have explained in the later half of my answer why it is `null` (thus the flaw in the code) and how it can be fixed. Please also see the second `ideone` (http://ideone.com/QVTjiD) which shows a way to fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I think you haven't grasped how [getdelim](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getline.html) works. It's first parameter is of type `char**`, which it uses to return a `char *`. So, your `runSysCall` should work the same way:-

```
void runSysCall(char *command, char **output)
{
  ....
  while(getdelim(output, &size, 0, cmdline) != -1);
  ...
}
```

Now, when you call runSysCall the second param must be of type `char**`, so...

```
char * getVendorOfTheProcesses()
{
  char * result = 0;
  runSysCall("cat /proc/cpuinfo | grep -i 'Model'", &result);

  return result;
}
```

Note that the pointer returned from `getVendorOfTheProcess` was malloc'd internally by `getdelim`. To avoid a leak, you must `free()` if after calling `getVendorOfTheProcess()`.

You should now get the results you expect.